# How to imaging/cloning the entire Ubuntu system on a server, and restore it on another server?

Tags: server, lubuntu, clone

I have an Ubuntu system installed on a hosting server, and I spent a lot of time to configure and install programs and requirements in the system that I need in my work..
I don't want to repeat the configuration and installation of these things when I install the system on another server..

Is there a way to copy/clone the entire Ubuntu system, and have it as a copy/image of the system, which I can easily restore and reinstall on the other server..

Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be done. Probably for a beginner the easiest method is to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).

You can also do a full disk image using the `dd` command to an external disk (after booting from live DVD/USB), and restore the image to the target machine - assuming the disk in the target machine is the same size (or larger) than in the source one (in case of a larger disk you will have some unallocated space on the disk after cloning the system).

However, any of these methods require physical access to the server to be able to boot it from a live media.

Also when cloning the system you should avoid using specific hardware drivers (eg. for the graphic card). The cloned system will usually work if you use only generic drivers that come with the kernel, but will usually not work if you use specific hardware drivers (unless the target machine has exactly the same hardware as the source one). But in case of a server it's probably not an issue - such specific drivers are usually used in desktop systems.

Also take into account that after cloning the system you may need to have to adjust some parameters (eg. network configuration) on the cloned server before booting it, to avoid for example IP address conflict.